# How to use jQuery $ in PHP HEREDOC

Tags: php, jquery

I have this definition in PHP:

```
$embedHtml = <<<FORM
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="toystory.jpg" />
        <img src="up.jpg" data-transition="fade"/>
        <img src="walle.jpg" />
        <img src="nemo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){$("#slider").nivoSlider({directionNav: false, controlNav: false, pauseTime: 4000});});
    </script>
FORM;
```

But I have an error about $ in my variable.

Is there any way to define a variable in PHP that has a $? Please consider that I should use $ in my jQuery code and also I can not define variables like this:

```
$a = '$(window).load(function(){$("#slider").nivoSlider({directionNav: false, controlNav: false, pauseTime: 4000});}); ';
```

Comment: Try to escape character with \

Comment: Take a look at output buffering...

Comment: What is the error you see? Have you tried escaping the $ with a \?

Comment: Jquery client side, php server side... any hint from this?

Comment: @Lelio Faieta i should create this html and send for a client

Comment: No, you should just echo JavaScript in php or keep JavaScript out of php and just in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using HEREDOC, have you tried using NOWDOC (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) 'Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings.' .  This allows you to have 'as is' text, without any substitution or escaping...

```
$embedHtml = <<<'FORM'
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="toystory.jpg" />
        <img src="up.jpg" data-transition="fade"/>
        <img src="walle.jpg" />
        <img src="nemo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){$("#slider").nivoSlider({directionNav: false, controlNav: false, pauseTime: 4000});});
    </script>
FORM;
```

Note the single quotes round the opening `FORM`.